# How to cast audio to Alexa using a my react native music player app?

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an app like Spotify with React Native (Expo bareflow), and I am building a feature to play music on Alexa speaker devices.

This feature is solely for casting audio to Alexa speakers; it is not a skill. My app does not offer voice interaction, and users can only interact via the mobile app.

I have tried using the libraries alexa-voice-service, react-native-upnp, and react-native-avs. I followed the instructions to set them up in the Android folder, and I attempted to disable Hermes. However, none of the libraries seem to be compatible with RN 0.71.8.

Have you ever implemented this feature in an Expo bareflow project? If so, how did you do it?

alexa-voice-service, react-native-upnp, and react-native-avs libraries don´t work in React Native 0.71.8

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.